# visual studio macro to execute a file from the solution

Tags: visual-studio, macros

I wrote a small tool which sits in my solution (as a project), which runs in the background and helps me debug my main project.

I'd like to run the tool with a macro but I haven't found how to get the build path and execute it in the background.

Any VB macro experts ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question partly, apparently you can get the solution path from within a macro like this:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(DTE.Solution.FullName)
```

I found this in some of the macros listed [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/WindowsVisualStudioMacros). Since you say you've got a project within that solution, you could try [`DTE.Solution.FindProjectItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution.findprojectitem.aspx) and progress from there. It's difficult to give more information without knowing more details about your exact scenario.